# welcome message js errpr

Tags: discord, discord.js

from this code im getting the error /home/container/welcome.js:9
message.channel.send(message)
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

````
  const channelId = "812458294085550121";
 bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    console.log(member);

    const message = [`Welcome <@${member.id}> to our server`]

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
    message.channel.send(message)
  })
}```
````

Comment: If the answer solved your problem: please mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem you seem to have is, that channel can not be found. Hence the `can not find property 'send' of undefined`.

Try this:

```js
 const channelId = "812458294085550121";
 bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    console.log(member);

    const welcomeMessage = `Welcome <@${member.id}> to our server`;

    const channel =  client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
    channel.send(welcomeMessage);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined 'message' in your code to receive the channel while you have 'message' defined as a message to send and not as an object. Also you made your message in an array what is a bit confusing, so what you also would need to do is access the message in the array with an index position. This should work:

```
const channelId = "812458294085550121"; // Define the channel id
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => { // Event listener when someone joined a server
    console.log(member); // Sends the member object in the console

    const message = [`Welcome <@${member.id}> to our server`] // Message in an array

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId) // Find the channel
    if(!channel) return console.log(`Channel doesn't exists`); // If the channel doesn't exists
    channel.send(message[0]); // Send the message in the channel
});
```